# Creating A new Route in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC, the default route url pattern is - url : "{controller}/{action}/{id}"

When I add a new route as shown below before the default route, the url for the default route is shown as something like Home/Index?id=5 and not Home/Index/5. How can this be fixed.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Name",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Browse", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Could you give name a default value? If so, that should solve the problem: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Name",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Browse", name = "" }
        );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default route will never be hit because the route you added is exactly the same, from a routing perspective.  So your route will catch everything that the default route would catch if it were the only one, or placed before yours.  Both will match one, two and three-segment URLs.

Comment: @user2813261 Do you strictly need the default route?  The only difference is yours has a different default for `action` and the third segment has a different name.

Answer (score 0):

That route is unnecessary and pretty much useless.
like what @asymptoticFault says, it serves the same purpose as the default one.